# How to create a very long level selection scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am in the process of creating a level selection scene for my first game. After looking here and there on the internet I realized that level selection is just another scene of game (Correct me if I am wrong).

My Game is going to have 1000+ levels. So my level select scene is going to be very long (vertical). And I think loading this long scene will be slow (have planned to use several animations and images).

Further, I have observed that some games like TwoDots and “Angry birds Action”, do not load all levels and instead, load current Plus 20 or 30 levels, and current minus 20 or 30 levels. And when we scroll up, it loads new levels and unload previous levels.

In the following image, I am scrolling to my previous levels and after showing 30 previous levels, it goes to a small loading at bottom (see below image at bottom there is a loading bar, and it will load previous 30 levels and unload top 30), and then loads more levels:

[image]

What should be done to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry but this is way too broad for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could use more than one scene for your level and then load those once player wants to see them via [SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("SceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html). Other than that it is important to get your scrolling performant. Scroll view will create a lot of redrawing, you might need to actually move the camera in order to create little overhead. When using a scroll view, make sure to use a rectMask2D instead of a mask in order to easy cull everything that is not in the players view (will create less draw calls).

Also consider to activate and deactivate game objects or to even have a pool of game objects that can represent your map. With object pooling you would make sure to not create any garbage.